# How to install xmlsec1 on windows

Tags: python-2.7, saml-2.0, xmlsec, libltdl, xmlsec1

I am using djangosaml2 and pysaml2 for sso authentication using SAML.

Pysaml2 requires xmlsec1 for security assertions.

I am able to install xmlsec1 on ubuntu 14.04. everything is working fine.

For windows platform, I am not able to install xmlsec1 library.

What I have tried-

1 Downloaded windows binary  from https://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html
2 When I try to access it is giving libltdl-7.dll missing error is getting

Answer (score 0):

In windows, download the xmlsec file using this [link](https://www.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/64bit/xmlsec1-1.2.20-win32-x86_64.7z).

Extract the file and set the path in the environment variable. if you don't want set the environment variable, specify the path link below

```
get_xmlsec_binary(["D:\\Softwares\\xmlsec1-1.2.20-win32-x86\\bin"])
```

Comment: I downloaded it using your link and get the exact same error.